# Inputting 30-something and -Ex42 with an output of 30 and Ex42

Tags: c++

I can't understand how I would do this.

The input will be:

```
3
13894
       30-something
-Ex42
```

and the output needs to be:

```
13894
30
Ex42
```

The main assignment is to make a function that converts a duodecimal number into the decimal format. I have figured that part out and don't need help with it. I've basically cut out all the code surrounding the duodecimal conversion and just included the stuff I can't figure out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int to_decimal(const string& str);

int main () {
    string str; // Initializes string str for input

    cin.ignore (256, '\n'); //ignores the 3 from the input

    while (getline(cin, str)) {
        //runs str through to_decimal and outputs
        cout << to_decimal(str) << endl;
    }
}

int to_decimal(const string& str) {
    int f = 0;
    string localString; // Initialize local string variable

    //sets local string to the same as inputted string
    localString = str; //used for local string erasing

    //This is the idea I have been working on and I cant figure it out
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < localString.length(); x++) {
        f = localString.at(x);
        if (isdigit(f)) {

        } else if (f == 'E'){
                
        } else if (f == 'e') {

        } else if (f == 'X') {

        } else if (f == 'x') {

        } else if (f == '-') {

        } else if (f == ' ') {

        } else {
            f = localString.length() - x;
            localString.erase(x, f);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ? "Ex42" isn't a number

Comment: @JHBonarius Its a duodecimal number. Normally BA42 but my teacher wants me to use to E for 11 and x for 10. I just need to figure out how to keep that number while getting rid of the -something from 30-something

Comment: Needs a bit more details or clarity on what you are trying to solve/do.

Comment: Those details are quite important. Those are not standard. IMHO it's a weird assignment anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused. You say that you need to convert duodecimal numbers to decimal, however in your sample output only the line that has `Ex` is converted, yet `30-something` stays 30, as if it is not converted - and `30` in duodecimal is `36` in decimal. Same for the number `13894`.

Assuming that you really want to convert all of the lines from duodecimal to decimal, you can base your solution on the standard library function `std::stoi()` which can convert a string from most number bases up to 36. It requires that the digits bigger than `9` are encoded using the letters in alphabetic order - `A` to `Z`. So you need to simply convert all you `x` to `a` and all you `e` to `b`. Example:

```
int to_decimal(const string& str) {
    bool foundDigit = false;
    std::string transformedString;
    for (auto c : str) {
        if (std::isdigit(c) || c == 'E' || c =='e' || c == 'X' || c == 'x') {
            foundDigit = true;

            // If needed, convert the character.
            if (c == 'E' || c == 'e') {
                c = 'b';
            } else if (c == 'X' || c == 'x') {
                c = 'a';
            }

            transformedString += c;
        } else if (foundDigit) {
            // Skip everything to the end of the line, if we've already found some digits
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return std::stoi(transformedString, 0, 12);
}
```

Comment: as this is an assignment, he's probably not allowed to use `stoi`... but he says he already has code for the conversion, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the characters and then do the conversion yourself, then you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool isNumber(const char c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
    case '0':
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
    case 'x':
    case 'X':
    case '-':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

std::string getNumber(std::istream& in)
{
    std::stringstream s;
    for (char c;in.get(c);)
    {
        if (isNumber(c)) {
            s << c;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (char c;in.get(c);)
    {
        if (!isNumber(c))
            break;
        s << c;
    }

    return s.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string bla = "3\n13894\n       30-something\n-Ex42\n";
    std::stringstream klaf{ bla };

    for (std::string s;(s = getNumber(klaf)) != "";)        //<- use a local stringstream as input to test
    //for (std::string s;(s = getNumber(std::cin)) != "";)  //<- use std::cin for input
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
3
13894
30-
e
-Ex42
```

So, not exactly what you were after, but it should at least get you a starting point to improve from. For example, you may want to remove `-` from `isNumber` and then change to logic in `getNumber` to only accept it as the first character in a new number.